# PHP version adoption stats?

Tags: php, version

Are there any statistics as to what percentage of servers are running PHP version 5.3+?

**2013-02-18:** 34% per [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/about/stats/) | 35% per [w3techs](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5.3/all) | [Drupal 8](http://drupal.org/requirements) requires 5.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty hard to have to get those kind of statistics.

You can find some here : http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5.3/all

```
PHP : 77.2% 
Version 5 : 72.3% 
Version 5.3: 13.3% 
W3Techs.com, 3 December 2011 
Percentage of websites using PHP


PHP : 77.9%
Version 5 : 74.1%
Version 5.3 : 23.1%
W3Techs.com, 19 June 2012
Percentage of websites using PHP
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a statistic here:
http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5.3/all

```
 5.3            |  17.2%      (from 13.3%/0.77)
```

(It was only 8% in June. So very steadily rising now.)